# Find chains of identical elements in ndarray and modify them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

I have ndarrays like [1,1,1,1,3,3,3].

I want that, if there are consecutive elements with the same value like the case of the example, the content of the identical chain is modified in this way: we calculate delta as the 0.1% of the identical value, subtract it to the first element of the chain and add it to the last, obtaining in the example:
[0.9999,1,1,1.0001,2.9997,3,3.0003].

Then I want to further modify the values inside the chain to make the distance balanced. For example there is a distance of 0.0002 between 0.9999 and 1.0001 and I have a total of 4 elements in the chain, so 0.0002/(4-1) = 0.000067. Finally I get [0.9999, 0.999967, 1.000034, 2.9997, 3, 3.0003].

How can I do this?
I tried with this simple code just to modify the extremes but it doesn't work:

```
def modify_extremes(arr):
    modified_arr = arr.astype(float)

    # Find indices where consecutive elements are not equal
    indices = np.where(np.diff(arr) == 0)[0] + 1

    # Iterate over the found indices and modify extremes
    for i in indices:
        modified_arr[i - 1] += 0.01
        modified_arr[i] -= 0.01

    return modified_arr
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need two functions: one to split consecutive integers and one to interpolate values. This is how you could split consecutive integers:

```
def split_consecutive_ints(lst):
    result = []
    current_group = [lst[0]]

    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        if lst[i] == lst[i - 1]:
            current_group.append(lst[i])
        else:
            result.append(current_group)
            current_group = [lst[i]]

    result.append(current_group)
    return result
```

This is how you could interpolate values in a list:

```
def interpolate_values(lst):
    first = lst[0]
    last = lst[-1]
    num_elements = len(lst)

    interpolated_values = [
        first + (last - first) * i / (num_elements - 1) for i in range(num_elements)
    ]

    return interpolated_values
```

And this is how you could call those functions on a list with integers:

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
new_x = []

chunks = split_consecutive_ints(x)
for chunk in chunks:
    if len(chunk) > 1:
        chunk[0] -= 0.01
        chunk[-1] += 0.01
        new_x.append(interpolate_values(chunk))
    else:
        new_x.append(chunk)

# >>> new_x
# >>> [[0.99, 0.9966666666666667, 1.0033333333333334, 1.01], [2.99, 3.0, 3.01], [4], [4.99, 4.995, 5.0, 5.005, 5.01]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to change the duplicates at the beginning and the end of your iterable, in this case numpy array. There is also a caveat, what your expectations are if you got two dupes in a row. In this case I assume the same as if the row is longer and set 0.99 to the first and 1.01 to the last.

```
def index_dupes(lst:list):
    comparator, *lst = lst
    start, end = [0]*2
    for num, el in enumerate(lst, start=1):
        if comparator == el:
            end += 1
        else:
            yield start, end
            start, end = [num] * 2
            comparator = el
    else:
        yield start, end


# reviewed for the second part of the question
def change_dupes(indxes, lst, proz = 0.0001):
    for vals in indxes:
        start, end = vals

        if start == end:
            yield lst[start]
            continue

        first = lst[start]*(1- proz)
        last  = lst[end]*(proz + 1)

        yield first
        # sentinel for consecutive indexes
        if not (end - start == 1):
            dist = end - start
            delta = lst[start] * proz * 2 / dist
            yield from (first + num*delta
                        for num, _ in enumerate(range(dist-1), start=1))
        yield last



if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4,4]
    # uses generators to avoid memory usage
    cd = change_dupes(index_dupes(test), test)
    print(list(cd))
    # >>> [0.9999, 0.9999666666666667, 1.0000333333333333, 1.0001, 2.9997, 3.0, 3.0003, 3.9996, 4.0004]
```